# "Stantes erant pedes nostri..."

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin, translation-explanation

Another little puzzle inside Little Office of the BVM, Baronius Press, which is based upon the Gallican Psalter.

Psalm cxxi has:

> *Stantes erant pedes nostri, in atriis tuis, Jerusalem.*

Which it translates:

> Our feet were wont to stand: in thy courts, O Jerusalem.

This translation surprises me because I cannot detect within the Latin sentence the element of **desire** nor **privation**. As a beginner, it seems to me to say, more simply:

> Our feet were standing in thy courts, O Jerusalem.

The first, mysterious (to me) translation fits the context better than my own. I just see no justification for it within the sentence itself.

Is this perhaps another Hebraism? Or some Latin idiom I have yet to learn? Or something else entirely?

Comment: There can be more to it here, but I cannot resist making this comment: Fitting context is more important than translating every sentence exactly as such. When translating text, a story is read in one language, understood, and retold in another language. If the desire or deprivation are understood to be there from context and English offers a simple way to convey it, why not? Justification need not be within the sentence itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm missing something, but:

I think your issue here may be with the English rather than the Latin. To say that something "was wont to do" something ("wont" with an *o* and no apostrophe rather than "want" with an *a*) is an archaic way to say that it "was used to doing" something or "used to do" something.

So rather than desire or privation, the English is saying (in a more modern translation)

> Our feet used to stand in your courts, Jerusalem.

or

> Or feet were accustomed to stand in your courts, Jerusalem.

Which seems like a translation closer to the original.

Comment: Ah, that seems to make my question off-topic? Shall I delete it?

Comment: @DavidCharles, I'm in favor of keeping it. It was a question about translating from Latin, although the answer turned out to be less related to Latin. (And I think the system won't allow you to delete a question with an answer with positive score.)

Comment: Yeah, since the *question* is about Latin, I'd say it should stay. You're safe!