Can we use the verb "sum" with the present participle "absens"?
I recall seeing "esse absens" on Google books, but I can't remember who was the writer. Anyway, is this correct in Latin? The verb "absum" already exists, and it means "to be absent", and "absens" is an adjective "absent", is there a difference between "absum" and "sum absens"?

Do you mean for Classical Latin, or for any and all periods?

@cmw all of them. Although something tells me that I can't say this In Classical Latin.

Your interesting question is (partly) related to these two previous ones: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/can-esse-be-used-with-a-present-participle and https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4256/stantes-erant-vs-stabant?noredirect=1&lq=1

Yes, you can, although you don't have to, as you point out.
Terence, Eunuchus, Line 192, Cum milite isto praesens, absens ut sis, "When you are with that soldier of yours, be absent from him."
A PHI search on the word #absens# also turns up some hits with esse in Cicero and some other places as well, all classical.

thank you. So can we use the verb "esse"(all the verbs) and its compounds when they are adjectives...?

@AntônioSilva You are most welcome. To answer your follow up question: I don't know, but I don't see why not. Here in the US, where the English idiom of "be doing", i.e., "be" + present participle, is preposterously common, pedagogues are at pains to instruct their young charges, "never do that in Latin!" However, it is clear that the Classical authors sometimes did that, although not to the preposterous extent that modern Americans do. When to use the idiom, and when to abstain, is an interesting question that I am not qualified to answer.

Yes, there are some examples of this construcion in Latin (by far more frequent in Late Latin -by influence of Greek- than in Classical Latin). For related discussion, see https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/can-esse-be-used-with-a-present-participle?noredirect=1&lq=1
